# How are parameters handled when passing functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html, there is the following example:

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
alert(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

Knowing only basic JavaScript and imperative programming, I am stumped by this programming style.  What happens during runtime?

I stepped through the code and inspected variables and found that the value of `x` is `NaN`.  How does it know that the argument to `isNaN` should be passed as argument `x` of the anonymous function?  In the first place, why does the actual parameter NaN of `isNotNaN` become the argument to `isNaN` (ie while `isNaN` expects an argument, why does it take it from the argument of `isNotNaN`)?

Comment: *"In the first place, why does the actual parameter `NaN` of `isNotNaN` become the argument to `isNaN`"* Because of the third line: `func(x)`. `func` is a reference to `isNaN` and `x` is `NaN`. This is not much different from any other function E.g. in `function foo(x) { return bar(x); }; foo(x)`, `foo` passes `x` along to `bar`. The only difference in your example is that `func` is determined dynamically.

Comment: **note** this function `negate` correctly work only with functions that takes just one parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to understand this might be with seeing what these things actually equal. Notice how `func` becomes the passed `isNaN` function.

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
/*

isNotNaN = function(x){
   return !isNaN(x)
}

*/

alert(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

Comment: That comment block is enlightening. However, where does the value of `x` come from when isNotNaN is invoked?

Comment: @OldGeezer: In the last line: `isNotNaN(NaN)`. You are passing `NaN`,

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `negate` both accepts a function as an argument and returns a function. The returned function will call the argument function, negating the return value. Thus, `isNotNaN` is a function. When it is called, it will call the function originally passed into `negate`, in this case `isNaN`. Whatever you call `isNotNaN` with will be passed to `isNaN`.

In essence, you're *configuring* a function with another function. This might be easier to see with a simpler (no argument function) example:

```
function addX(x) {
    return function(y) {
        return x+y;
    };
}

var add2 = addX(2);
console.log(add2(2)); // 4

var add3 = addX(3);
console.log(add3(7)); // 10
```

Now, take this one step further and imagine you passed a function into `addX` instead of a value.

By the way, this is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set this:

```
   var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
```

And when calling isNotNaN(x)so it is like you call negate(isNaN)(x). You can also use a named function instead of the anonymous here so we say:

```
    function negate(func) {
      return xValue.call(this, x); //to be in the context of the xValue function
      };
   }
    var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
    alert(isNotNaN(NaN));

    function xValue(x) {
       return !func(x);
    }

    But then you have to take care about the context.
```