# Parameters of a function variable

Tags: javascript, first-class-functions

After distilling the answers to [How are parameters handled when passing functions in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669993/how-are-parameters-handled-when-passing-functions-in-javascript) I ended up with one question I need to clarify.

In the sample below:

```
function plus2(x) { return x+2; }

var Q = function(y) { return plus2(y); }

alert(Q(10));
```

Why does the invocation of `Q` with an argument of 10 result in `y` getting the value 10?

Comment: because it is same as `function Q(y) {...}`

Comment: I get 12: http://jsfiddle.net/4ce9nch0/

Comment: Would you question y being 10 with: `var Q = function(y) { alert(y); } Q(10);`?

Comment: @AdrianLynch Yes I still would, because of my usual understanding of the meaning of the = sign and my poor understanding of functions as first class objects.  I replaced the anonymous function with a named function and it became clearer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Replacing the anonymous function with a named function gave me a little bit more clarity:

```
function plus2(x) { return x+2; }
function dummy(y) { return plus2(y); }

var Q = dummy;

alert(Q(10));
```

`Q` then becomes a sort of alias for `dummy`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function plus2(x) { return x+2; }

var Q = function(y) { return plus2(y); }

alert(Q(10));
```

Will alert 12. `y`is 10 as it is the value 10 which is passd as an argument and then assigned to the function parameter `y`. Equivalent

```
var y = 10; // call of Q

var x = y; call of plus2 in Q
x = x + 2;

y = x; // return of plus2

alert y; // return of Q
```